# Handling singularities in squircle parametric equations

Tags: python, mathematics

In order to plot a squircle using its parametric equations:

[image]

The equations can be found in page 9 of this
[this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02174.pdf):

> Fong, Chamberlain. "Squircular Calculations." arXiv preprint arXiv:1604.02174 (2016).

Unfortunately the following singularities are not handled by those equations:

- For `t = 0`, `t = pi/2`, `t = pi`, `t = 3pi/2`, and `t=2*pi`

Here is the code to plot these equations in Python

```py
"""Plot squircle shape using its parametric equations"""
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sqrt, cos, sin, sign
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# FG stands for Fernandez-Guasti who introduced the algebric equations.
def FG_param(r, s, t):
    x = np.ones_like(t)
    y = np.ones_like(t)
    for i, _t in enumerate(t):
        if np.isclose(_t, 0.0):
            x[i] = r
            y[i] = 0.0
        elif np.isclose(_t, pi/2.0):
            x[i] = 0.0
            y[i] = r
        elif np.isclose(_t, pi):
            x[i] = -r
            y[i] = 0.0
        elif np.isclose(_t, 3*pi/2.0):
            x[i] = 0.0
            y[i] = -r
        elif np.isclose(_t, 2*pi):
            x[i] = r
            y[i] = 0.0
        else:
            x[i] = r*sign(cos(t[i]))/(s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(sin(t[i])))*sqrt(1 - sqrt(1-s**2*sin(2*t[i])**2))
            y[i] = r*sign(sin(t[i]))/(s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(cos(t[i])))*sqrt(1 - sqrt(1-s**2*sin(2*t[i])**2))
    return x, y

s = 0.7
r = 1.0
NTHETA = 90
t = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, NTHETA)

x, y = FG_param(r, s, t)

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5)
plt.show()
```

The function `FG_param` looks very clumsy. I appreciate any help to make it more compact and neat.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible to simplify via knowing that boolean statements return `0` or `1` if they are coerced to; for example, `np.isclose(_t, pi/2.0)` returns `1` if true, so that can be inverted (display zero if matched) and then multiplied by the RHS to remove it; the equation can be restructured to be `r + xsin(...)`, where `x` is the condition. This can be repeated for all remaining conditions and structured accordingly. I may provide a code sample

Comment: Something *sort* of like this, but this is not 100% correct: `x[i] = r * \
             (np.isclose(_t, 0.0) or np.isclose(_t, 2*pi)) * \
             (not np.isclose(_t, 0.0) or np.isclose(_t, 2*pi)) * \
             (1 - (not np.isclose(_t, pi))) * \
             (not np.isclose(_t, 3*pi/2.0))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different solution.  The singularities occur when sin(_t) or cos(_t) is zero.  So check for those conditions.

```
def FG_param(r, s, t):
    x = np.ones_like(t)
    y = np.ones_like(t)

    for i, _t in enumerate(t):
        sin_t = sin(_t)
        cos_t = cos(_t)

        if np.isclose(sin_t, 0.0):
            x[i] = -r if np.isclose(_t, pi) else r
            y[i] = 0.0

        elif np.isclose(cos_t, 0.0):
            x[i] = 0.0
            y[i] = r if _t < pi else -r

        else:
            radical = sqrt(1 - sqrt(1 - s**2 * sin(2*_t)**2))

            x[i] = r*sign(cos_t) / (s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(sin_t)) * radical
            y[i] = r*sign(sin_t) / (s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(cos_t)) * radical

    return x, y
```

Comment: The singularities occur also when `s=0`

Comment: @Navaro: Exactly. In that case (i.e: `s=0`) the map will be a circle with radius `r`.

Comment: @Navaro s==0 wasn't handled in the original code, so I didn't handle it either.  It would be an easy case to handle.

Comment: @RootTwo: Yes, you could just add something like this at the top of the function: `if s == 0: return r*cos(t), r*sin(t)`

Answer (score 2):

This solution is an order of magnitude faster than the other ones.  It uses numpy functions, so there aren't any explicit loops. `np.where` chooses values that keep the equations from blowing up where the denominator would go to zero.  Case for `s == 0` is handled separately.

```
def FG_param1(r, s, t):

    if s == 0:
        return r*cos(t), r*sin(t)


    sin_t = sin(t)
    cos_t = cos(t)

    radical = sqrt(1 - sqrt(1 - s**2 * sin(2*t)**2))

    x_denom = np.where(np.isclose(sin_t, 0.0), 1.0, s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(sin_t))
    x = r * sign(cos_t) * np.where(np.isclose(sin_t, 0.0, 1e-12), 1.0, radical / x_denom)

    y_denom = np.where(np.isclose(cos_t, 0.0), 1.0, s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(cos_t))
    y = r * sign(sin_t) * np.where(np.isclose(cos_t, 0.0, 1e-12), 1.0, radical / y_denom)

    return x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, and untested, how about:

```
def FG_param(r, s, t):
    x = np.ones_like(t)
    y = np.ones_like(t)

    for i, _t in enumerate(t):
        radical = sqrt(1 - sqrt(1 - s**2 * sin(2*_t)**2))

        try:
            x[i] = r*sign(cos(_t)) / (s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(sin(_t))) * radical

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            x[i] = -r if np.isclose(_t, pi) else r

        try:
            y[i] = r*sign(sin(_t)) / (s*sqrt(2)*np.abs(cos(_t))) * radical

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            y[i] = r if _t < pi/2.0 else -r

    return x, y
```